# Insert xml node in specific location

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I would like to build the following xml:

```
<Item>
    <Name>Hello</Name>
    <Date>2014-01-01</Date>
    <Hero>1</Helo>
</Item>
```

Given the following code structure, how would I insert the `<Date>` node **before** the hero node?

```
item = etree.SubElement(self.xml_node, 'Item')
etree.SubElement(item, 'Name').text = 'Hello'
etree.SubElement(item, 'Hero').text = 1
# Now, how to insert the 'Date' element before the Hero element?
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using `etree.SubElement` always appends the subelement to the end of the parent `item`. So instead, to *insert* a new element at a particular location, use `item.insert(pos, subelement)`:

```
import lxml.etree as etree
xml_node = etree.Element("node")
item = etree.SubElement(xml_node, 'Item')
etree.SubElement(item, 'Name').text = 'Hello'
etree.SubElement(item, 'Hero').text = '1'
etree.SubElement(item, 'Date').text = '2014-01-01'
item.insert(1, item[-1])
print(etree.tostring(xml_node, pretty_print=True))
```

yields

```
<node>
  <Item>
    <Name>Hello</Name>
    <Date>2014-01-01</Date>
    <Hero>1</Hero>
  </Item>
</node>
```

---

Each node in an ElementTree can occur at only one place. So although

```
etree.SubElement(item, 'Date').text = '2014-01-01'
```

places the `<Date>` node at the end of `<item>`,

```
item.insert(1, item[-1])
```

*moves* the last node in `item`, i.e. the `<Date>` node, to position 1 (making it the *second* child in `<Item>`).

Answer (score 1):

`etree` elements behave like lists, so just use `.insert()`:

```
>>> from xml.etree import ElementTree as etree

>>> parent = etree.Element('parent')

>>> etree.SubElement(parent, 'child1')
<Element 'child1' at 0x108797048>

>>> etree.SubElement(parent, 'child2')
<Element 'child2' at 0x108797188>

>>> el = etree.Element('child-one-and-a-half')
>>> parent.insert(1, el)

>>> etree.dump(parent)
<parent><child1 /><child-one-and-a-half /><child2 /></parent>
```